# How to move all theme templates into a subfolder WP

Tags: blog, php

I'm looking for a wordpress function to move theme's templates into a subfolder (mytheme/templates). Anyone know?

The solution can be paid (plugin) or free.

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish? Do you have some *need* for the template files to be in a subfolder, or is it just for aesthetics?

Comment: Just a side note: You could store the complete WordPress in a [subdirectory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory).

Answer (score 1):

Not easy to do. You can create redirect template and assign templates based on page ID

```
    <?php
    if (is_page('629')) { include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/pages/homepage.php');}
    elseif (is_page('186')) { include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/pages/generalpage.php');}
    else { include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/pages/defaultpage.php');
} ?>
```

See [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/subdirectories-for-page-templates-sidebars-and-singles?replies=12) for more details